# SQL/PHP Select a follower that you don't follow from someone who follows you

Tags: php, sql, twitter

I'm working on a website comparable to Twitter. You can follow people and post messages.

I want to select one person who I don't follow who is followed by someone who I follow.
Hope you got that sentence!

This is the SQL query I currently use, but it doesn't work correctly. It still shows persons I already follow.

```
SELECT a.naar_id
FROM wievolgtwie a, wievolgtwie b
WHERE a.van_id = $row[0]
    AND b.van_id = $_SESSION[id]
    AND a.naar_id != $_SESSION[id]
    AND a.naar_id != b.naar_id
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Explanation:

`naar_id` the id of the person that is followed by `van_id`.

`van_id` is the id who follows `naar_id`.

(`van_id`, `naar_id`)
So rows (1, 3) and (2, 3) means that id 1 and 2 both follow id 3.

`wievolgtwie` is the table with the 'whofollowswho' information.

```
van_id, naar_id
+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |
| 1    | 3    |
| 2    | 1    |
| 2    | 4    |
| 3    | 4    |
| 3    | 2    |
+------+------+
```

`$row[0]` is the person you follow where I want to select someone from who them follows but you don't.

`$_SESSION[id]` is your id (the person who's logged in).

So if `$row[0]` = 2 and the person logged in has id 1 'me'; I want to get id 4 (because id 1 is me and I don't follow id 4) (See example table)

Does anybody know the right query for what I want to achieve?

Thanks in advance,

Jeroen

Comment: You're starting with `SELECT a.naar_id` which you've defined as "the id of the person you follow."  Is that not guaranteed to always return an id of someone you already follow?  Or do I just not understand your table?

Comment: Yeah sorry, that should be 'the id of the person that is followed by van_id'

Comment: I added an example table. I hope it's a little clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is put a subquery in your where clause to make sure that there is no row with your id and the naar_id in the database and filter by that. It should be something like this:

```
SELECT a.naar_id
FROM wievolgtwie a, wievolgtwie b
WHERE a.van_id = $row[0]
    AND b.van_id = $_SESSION[id]
    AND a.naar_id != $_SESSION[id]
    AND a.naar_id != b.naar_id
    AND b.vaan_id NOT IN (SELECT vaan_id
                            FROM wievolgtwie
                           WHERE naar_id = a.naarId)
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Be ware of possible pseudo-code, but the concept should work.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would work but the a. and b. stuff put aparantly subqueries were the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct query which I figured out after Simon Aronsson answered me! So thank you Simon.

```
SELECT naar_id
FROM wievolgtwie
WHERE van_id = $row[0]
    AND naar_id != $_SESSION[id]
    AND naar_id NOT IN (
            SELECT naar_id
            FROM wievolgtwie
            WHERE van_id = $_SESSION[id])
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

It didn't need `a.` and `b.` stuff. Just a subquery.